# How to meassure disk access

Tags: windows, performance

How can I meassure the disk access on Windows Server 2012?
We have some storages attached via iSCI one with SSD and the other not. I would like to compare the disk access speed. In order to figure out if our iSCI network is a bottle neck or not.
Visual Studio 2013 seems to run to slow, so we are trying to find out if the File System Access is too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html), it will measure sequential and random speeds of reads and writes, as well as using different sized data and random and zeroed data.

Comment: Have you tried this actually on a Windows server can it be harmful in a productive environment?

Comment: You would want to run it during a time when as few systems as possible will be accessing the storage array, or else you won't get consistent numbers. Be warned that some caching systems in the storage array or your virtualization hypervisor can cause irregular results as well.

Answer (score 1):

Performance counters Seconds/Read and Seconds/Write are the best measurement as they show you how long it takes to get an answer - and if that gets slow you are overloaded. Anything else is extremely situational (queue length etc.) and allows no direct comparison of load levels and / or proper response times.

Comment: Where can thiese performance counters be seen?

Comment: Where all can be seen. You do know windows performance counters, basic knowledge of any beginner admin?

Comment: I am developer who tries to assist from time to time our admin so please be tolerant ;)

Comment: A more useful answer could be:  Please check out [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115.aspx) for details about this cool feature.